# Twigjs and dynamic translations

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm facing a problem, I use in Symfony2 twigjs and assetic to render some of my templates dynamically.

I've read the doc, the source, and the tests.

In `TransFilterCompilerTest.php/testCompileDynamicTranslations` it seems that a

`{{ 'foo' | trans }}` in my twig template

would be replaced in the twigjs template by

`'this.env_.filter("trans",'...` in my twigjs one

**but** in my compiled js I only have `sb.append(twig.filter.escape(this.env_, "posted", "html", null, true));`

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the TwigJs\JsCompiler::getDefine('locale') returning null. I can't seem to find the configuration for it.

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation, I found out that while the translation compile filter was added several months ago in JMSTwigJsBundle, the required features were only added recently to Assetic. Using the released versions of the libraries will not work. For now, master from git must be used.

Using the deps file...

```
[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
```

The languages supported by the site must be specified as a parameter. I added it to my config.yml file.

```
parameters:
    assetic.variables:
        locale: ['en', 'fr']
```

Finally, the file set must indicate that it varies based on the locale.

```
{% javascripts vars=["locale"]
    '@AcmeBundle/Resources/views/Default/some_template.html.twig'
    filter="twig_js"
%}
```

Here is a sample template for completeness:

```
{% twig_js name="some_template" %}
<b>{{'test.say.hello' | trans({"%name%": name|default("World")})}}</b>
```

The twig.js bootstrap file must also be loaded prior to the template definitions. Calling a template is as expected:

```
Twig.render(some_template, {name: 'CoBaLt2760'})
```